# Multiple questions in one view (RecyclerView) in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

My issue is more complicated than the regular quiz app.

I know for simpler quiz apps where there is one question along with multiple answers; you can use a single variable to track which answer the user has currently selected and as the user changes response the variable changes to match.

For my situation, it's more complex, I have a view where there are multiple questions in the view and each question has two responses that a user can select from.

My question is, should I be using an array of array that holds both the 'question id' along with the 'answer id' the user selected?

The tricker part for me at least is that the view is in a recyclerView so if the user scrolls all the way to the end of the list and then back up, some of the selected answers are removed, so how do I perform the check to ensure that answers do not get wiped out by the recyclerview on scrolling?

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve?